# How to retry the current loop even though the connection via proxy is failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, beautifulsoup

So I have a bunch of links that I want to scrap, but what often happens is that in the middle of the loop (when tried to connect to a random link), suddenly the connection via proxy is failing, the loop is stopped and my program closes.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#Setting Proxy
proxies = {"http": "http://232.454.676.898:8888"}

#List Of Links
link_strings = ['http://foo1.com','http://foo2.com','http://foo3.com', ... ,'http://foo999.com']

for link in link_strings:
    url = link

    uClient = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    page_html = uClient.text
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    #Do some scrapping
```

So, how to handle this?
Should I trying to connect to via proxy until succeed? But how to do that?
Or should I run the current loop again? But how to do that?

Comment: Use a try-except block to catch the exception, and handle it differently.

Comment: Could you give me the example of the code please?

Comment: A normal try-except with an explicit exception from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try catching the exception thrown by `requests.get()` and loop until the connection works:

```
exception = True
while (exception):
    exception = False
    try:
        uClient = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        exception = True
```

Be aware that ***this could create an infinite loop*** if the connection never works! Instead, you could `continue` when the connection fails:

```
try:
    uClient = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    continue
```

Comment: Including a retries counter could be a good idea.